# BeanProperties.list().observe() does not propagate ListChangeEvent

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface

I have some `Data` class that contains observable list of items:

```
public class Data {
    private final IObservableList items = WritableList.withElementType(Item.class);

    public IObservableList getItems() {
       return items;        
    }
}
```

When I bind directly to items everything is fine:

```
data.addListChangeListener(myListener); //OK
```

But when I bind to items via `BeanProperties.list()` `ListChangeEvent` does not propagated

```
BeanProperties.list(Data.class, "items", Item.class).
    observe(data).addListChangeListener(myListener); //Not working
```

My goal is to automatically add rows to (and remove from) Tree.

```
Realm realm = SWTObservables.getRealm(composite.getDisplay());
IListProperty listProperty = BeanProperties.list(Data.class, "items", Item.class);
IObservableFactory observableFactory = listProperty.listFactory(realm);
ObservableListTreeContentProvider contentProvider = new ObservableListTreeContentProvider(observableFactory, null);
treeViewer.setContentProvider(contentProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `BeanProperties` does not expect that property will be `IObservableList`. So I have implemented my own `ObservableListProperty`. It works *only* with properties of `IObservableList` type.

```
public class ObservableListProperty extends ListProperty {
    private final PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor;
    private final Class elementType;

    public ObservableListProperty(Class beanClass, String propertyName) {
        this(beanClass, propertyName, null);
    }

    public ObservableListProperty(Class beanClass, String propertyName, Class elementType) {
        propertyDescriptor = BeanPropertyHelper.getPropertyDescriptor(beanClass, propertyName);
        if (elementType == null) {
            elementType = BeanPropertyHelper.getCollectionPropertyElementType(propertyDescriptor);
        }
        this.elementType = elementType;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getElementType() {
        return elementType;
    }

    @Override
    public IObservableList observe(Realm realm, Object source) {
        IObservableList list = (IObservableList)BeanPropertyHelper.readProperty(source, propertyDescriptor);
        return new DecoratingObservableList(list, false);
    }
}
```